# How I can put this expression within a ng-bind?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
<p><timer end-time="{{fechaFinal}}">{{days}} Días, {{hours}} Horas, {{minutes}} Minutos, {{seconds}} Segundos.</timer></p>
```

I tried putting this and does not work

```
<p><timer end-time="{{fechaFinal}}" ng-bind="days + 'Días, ' + hours + ' Horas,' + minutes + ' Minutos, ' + seconds + ' Segundos.'"></timer></p>
```

Comment: Could you post the error message you're getting? That expression seems OK to me.

Comment: There is no issue with the ng-bind here. What exactly is the problem? Are you expecting the timer directive to work in a different way?

Comment: It does not show me any error console, but only shows me " Days, Hours , Minutes, Seconds . " without the values ​​of the variables.

Comment: @pratik-bhattacharya I'm working on a .tpl file of Prestashop.

Comment: works fine... post the rest of your directive https://jsfiddle.net/r0m4n/mwcy38b9/